# get rows from a table where value of field x is maximum

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables **myTable** and **myTable2** in a mysql database:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    number INT,
    version INT, 
    date DATE 
) ENGINE MyISAM;

INSERT INTO myTable
    (`id`, `number`, `version`, `date`)
VALUES
    (1, '123', '1', '2016-01-12'),
    (2, '123', '2', '2016-01-13'),
    (3, '124', '1', '2016-01-14'),
    (4, '124', '2', '2016-01-15'),
    (5, '124', '3', '2016-01-16'),
    (6, '125', '1', '2016-01-17')
;

CREATE TABLE myTable2 (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    myTable_id INT
) ENGINE MyISAM;

INSERT INTO myTable2
    (`id`, `myTable_id`)
VALUES
    (1, 1),
    (2, 1),
    (3, 2),
    (4, 2),
    (5, 3),
    (6, 3),
    (7, 4),
    (8, 4),
    (9, 4),
    (10, 5),
    (11, 6)
;
```

The field **myTable2.myTable_id** is a foreign key of **myTable.Id**.

I would like to get all the rows from **myTable** where **myTable2.myTable_id = myTable.Id** and the value of the field **version** in **myTable** is the maximum for every corresponding value for the field **number** in **myTable**.

I tried something like this:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    myTable, 
    myTable2 
WHERE 
    myTable.version = (SELECT MAX(myTable.version) FROM myTable)
```

But the above query does not return the correct data. The correct query should output this:

```
Id     number    version    date
2      123       2          2016-01-13
5      124       3          2016-01-16
6      125       1          2016-01-17
```

Please help!

Comment: yuo have two row for each myTable_id in table 2 this mean you want two row for each realation of max in tablle1? or you have some other condition for get only one row for table 2?

Comment: I have 3 rows for myTable.Id = 4, 1 row for myTable.Id = 5 and 1 row for myTable.Id = 6. I don't necessarily have two rows for each

Comment: Yes ... but the question remain  .. you want a relation for each of this row  or have other conditions for reduce the matc?

Comment: @user765368 posted another solution to your query.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this is to get the max version for each number in myTable in a derived table and join with that:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    m.* 
FROM 
    myTable m
JOIN
    myTable2 m2 ON m.id = m2.myTable_id
JOIN
    (
    SELECT number, MAX(version) AS max_version 
    FROM myTable
    GROUP BY number
    ) AS derived_table
 ON m.number  = derived_table.number 
AND m.version = derived_table.max_version
```

With your sample data this produces a result like this:

```
id  number  version date
6   125     1       2016-01-17
5   124     3       2016-01-16
2   123     2       2016-01-13
```

Answer (score 1):

your Query is logically wrong. Here is the correct one

```
SELECT 
 * 
FROM 
 myTable, 
 myTable2 
WHERE 
 (myTable.version,myTable.number) in 
  (SELECT MAX(myTable.version),number FROM myTable group by number)
 and myTable.id=myTable2.id
```

Here is the sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/74a67/4/0

Answer (score 0):

This is the query posted for the previous edited question

```
SELECT * FROM myTable 
inner join myTable2 on myTable.id = myTable2.mytable_id
WHERE (version, number) in 
  (SELECT MAX(version), number FROM myTable group by number)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution with using subquery simply as:

```
# Selecting desired result..
SELECT t1.id, t1.number, t1.version, t1.date 
FROM myTable As t1 JOIN
    # subquery to select max version and its corresponding
    # number form myTable
    (SELECT number, max(version) As max_ver FROM myTable
        GROUP BY number
    ) As t2 ON  t1.number = t2.number and t1.version = t2.max_ver

# Now checking for foreign key..
WHERE t1.id IN (SELECT mytable_id FROM myTable2);
```

Was it helpful..

Comment: @user765368 check my solution whether it satisfies you or not...It is tested and runs correctly, gives output as you want...